# How to install Mapserver in nginx?

Tags: mapserver, linux

I was istalled Mapserver:

```
sudo apt-get install libgd2-xpm-dev
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cgi-mapserver mapserver-bin
```

and istall nginx:

```
sudo apt-get install nginx
sudo apt-get install spawn-fcgi
```

But what i gonna do now to Mapserver work in nginx? Can you give me a some links to tutorials?
OS: Ubuntu.

**UPDATE**

Okey. I found fastcgi [config](http://pl.it-usenet.org/thread/12216/11779/):

```
#!/bin/sh
MAPSERV_PORT=9001
USER=www-data
DAEMON=/usr/local/bin/mapserv
CHILDREN=5

# the -F switch of spawn-fcg does not work when the -n swich
# is set. using multiwatch instead
# see http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/spawn-fcgi.1.html

exec setuidgid $USER spawn-fcgi \
  -a 127.0.0.1 \
  -p $MAPSERV_PORT \
  -u $USER \
/usr/bin/multiwatch -f $CHILDREN $DAEMON
```

Now how to connect it to nginx?

**UPDATE2**

Now i add to the file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default follow lines:

```
   location /mapserver/ {
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9001;

            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/local/run/spawnscript;
            fastcgi_param PATH_INFO /usr/local/run/ spawnscript;
   }
```

Where `/usr/local/run/spawnscript` path to my fastcgi config.

After i do:

```
/usr/lib/cgi-bin/mapserv -v
```

and get:

```
/usr/lib/cgi-bin/mapserv: /usr/local/lib/libgdal.so.1: no version information available (required by /usr/lib/libmapserver-6.2.1.so)
 MapServer version 6.2.1 OUTPUT=GIF OUTPUT=PNG OUTPUT=JPEG SUPPORTS=PROJ
 SUPPORTS=GD SUPPORTS=AGG SUPPORTS=FREETYPE SUPPORTS=CAIRO SUPPORTS=SVG_SYMBOLS
 SUPPORTS=ICONV SUPPORTS=FRIBIDI SUPPORTS=WMS_SERVER SUPPORTS=WMS_CLIENT SUPPORTS=WFS_SERVER
 SUPPORTS=WFS_CLIENT SUPPORTS=WCS_SERVER SUPPORTS=SOS_SERVER SUPPORTS=FASTCGI
 SUPPORTS=THREADS SUPPORTS=GEOS INPUT=JPEG INPUT=POSTGIS INPUT=OGR INPUT=GDAL INPUT=SHAPEFILE
```

How i understand mapserver was installed correct.

Now i do:

```
sudo service nginx start
```

Go to `localhos/mapserver/` but see only `Welcome to nginx` page. Whats wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solve this problem. But i cant paste all configuration files here becouse too much text lines. I post in here: http://dotrem.blogspot.ru/2013/06/mapservernginxfastcgi-on-ubuntu.html.
Maybe its help to someone.

Comment: Instead of spawn-fcgi you can use supervisor. If you do so you won't need to create the init.d script.

Answer (score 0):

```
 apt-get install cgi-mapserver mapserver-bin
```

Then this worked for me: http://www.howtoforge.com/serving-cgi-scripts-with-nginx-on-debian-squeeze-ubuntu-11.04-p3
except i make:

```
root  /usr/lib;
```

http://domain.com/cgi-bin/mapserv

> No query information to decode. QUERY_STRING is set, but empty.